# Javascript - array length includes 0 index even if empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var array = [];

array[1] = {
  test: true
};

console.log(array.length);
```

returns `2` as it's still counting index 0 even though it's empty. Is there anyway to avoid this so my output of length would be `1`?

Comment: Welcome to sparse arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You have created a [sparse array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description)

Use an object instead, then `Object.keys(obj)` will return number of entries

```js
var obj = {}

obj[1] = "test";

console.log(
  Object.keys(obj).length // shows the number of elements
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count only defined elements, use `filter` method.

```js
var array = [];

array[1] = {
  test: true
};

console.log(array.filter(e => e !== undefined).length);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to remove index 0 but preserve index 1 value without it being set as index 0?

Comment: @user3662307: No. Check out the link to sparse arrays above.  There is nothing at index 0, but the length is simply one more than the largest numeric index.